# Show that $f^*R$ is an equivalence relation if $R$ is

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $f \colon A \to B$ be a function, and $R$ a relation on $B$.  We
define a relation $f^*R$ on $A$ by $a_1 \mathrel{f^*R} a_2$ provided
$f(a_1)\mathrel{R} f(a_2)$.  Show that $f^*R$ is an equivalence
relation if $R$ is.

I was given this problem, and I am not sure I completely understand what it means- does it mean that f(a) R f(b) is a equivalent relation then a R b is also an equivalent relation? I don't know if where to start on this proof and if I need to prove transitivity, symmetry, and reflexivity for the equivalence relation.

Comment: The other way around, you want to show that if $R$ is an equivalence relation then $f^*R$ is as well.  As for how to prove it is... you do it in exactly the same way you have done the dozens of other examples you should have seen by this point.

Comment: Check to see whether you have $a$ is related to itself in every case... that is, check that $a f^*R a$... that is, check that $f(a)Rf(a)$.  Use that $R$ is an equivalence relation.  Similarly, if $a,b$ are elements of $A$ and you happen to have $af^*R b$, check to see whether or not $bf^*R a$ must be true as well.  Again... use that $R$ is an equivalence relation and it should be immediate.